# Ansible - environment variables from .env file

Tags: ansible, environment-variables

I am trying to setup a playbook which will run the command to check status of the service installed in the target machine. The command will only work only if the `.env file` executed. The command to execute the `.env file` is `.<space>./.env_file_name` and the file contains list of environment variables like export `JAVA_HOME=/optware/java/jdk/1.2.`

I tried to execute the environment file before running the command with the below playbook, but it is not working.

```
- hosts: name
  tasks: 
    - name: `execute env file`
      command: . ./.env_file_name
      register: result
```

Is there any playbook to run the executable environment file to set the environments present on the target machine and then run our command??

Comment: Usually the .env or any other files are sourced using `source` keyword in shell. try that. `command: source <path>`

Comment: Do you expect to use the env vars in other tasks? Because it's not possible this way. If you want to use them in the same task, then you should use the [`shell` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html). Otherwise, to use environment variables in tasks execution, you need to use [`environment` keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html)

Comment: @Zigarn I need to use the env variables in other task. do you have any example playbook to run .env file and to use the env variables in other tasks

Comment: Note, the `.` and `source` command are virtually the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20097303/320399

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42255589/320399

Answer (score 19):

First, the `. ./.env_file_name` syntax is a **shell** syntax and cannot work with the [`command` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#command-module), you need to use the [`shell` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html).

Secondly, the shell environment context is reset at every task as each is an ssh command round-trip (so a new shell session), and loading the environment variables in one task will not not make them available for next tasks.

Depending on your context, you have some options:

#### 1. Inventory environment variables

The best option is to have the environment at your inventory side in a variable with different value for each group/host through [`group_vars`/`host_vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables), then to use it for the [`environment` keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html)

```yaml
# host_vars/my_host.yml
---
env_vars:
  VAR1: key1
  VAR2: key2
```

```yaml
- hosts: my_host
  tasks: 
    - name: Display environment variables
      command: env
      environment: "{{ env_vars }}"
```

Pros:

- full ansible solution
- will work for environment of every module

Cons:

- need to know the environment variables at ansible side

#### 2. Loading environment variables for every tasks

If your tasks are all `shell`/`command` (which I don't advise, as it's better to use appropriate [ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/modules_by_category.html) whenever possible), you can simply load the env file every time with shell module

```yaml
- hosts: my_host
  tasks: 
    - name: Display environment variables
      shell: |
        . ./.env_file_name && env

    - name: Do another action
      shell: |
        . ./.env_file_name && do_something_else
```

Pros:

- no need to know the environment variables at ansible side

Cons:

- limited to tasks with `shell` module

#### 3. Load environment variables from env_file into ansible fact

This option is to parse the env file once and for all and load it in an ansible fact to use with the `environment` keyword.

```yaml
- hosts: my_host
  tasks: 
    - name: Get env file content
      slurp:
        src: ./.env_file_name
      register: env_file_content

    - name: Parse environment
      set_fact:
        env_vars: "{{ ('{' + (env_file_content.content | b64decode).split('\n') | select | map('regex_replace', '([^=]*)=(.*)', '\"\\1\": \"\\2\"') | join(',') + '}') | from_json }}"

    - name: Display environment variables
      command: env
      environment: "{{ env_vars }}"
```

Or, if the env file need to be executed instead of directly parsed:

```yaml
- hosts: my_host
  tasks: 
    - name: Get env file content
      shell: . ./.env_file_name && env
      register: env_file_result

    - name: Parse environment
      set_fact:
        env_vars: "{{ ('{' + env_file_result.stdout_lines | map('regex_replace', '([^=]*)=(.*)', '\"\\1\": \"\\2\"') | join(',') + '}') | from_json }}"

    - name: Display environment variables
      command: env
      environment: "{{ env_vars }}"
```

Pros:

- will work for environment of every module
- no need to know the environment variables at ansible side

Cons:

- could fail on bad formatting of file

Comment: Thanks for this! Although the big problem I think is the regex, because it doesn't support quotes around values, and doesn't support comments either (`#`).

Comment: Right! It can be done by adding `| map('regex_replace', '#.*', '') | map('trim') | reject()` before the `| map('regex_replace'` to remove the comments and change the regex to `'([^=]*)=['"]?(.*)['"]?'` to handle simple cases of quoted values.

Comment: So I followed your instructions and used: `{{ ('{' + (env_file_content.content | b64decode).split('\n') | select | map('regex_replace', '#.*', '') | map('trim') | reject() | map('regex_replace', '([^=]*)=['\"]?(.*)['\"]?', '\"\\1\": \"\\2\"') | join(',') + '}') | from_json }}` but unfortunately this didn't work. Although I feel this might be going more towards a separate question, do you know what I'm missing?

Comment: I think I was wrong (didn't test...): use `select` instead of `reject`

Comment: I couldn't get this working and managed to find an answer that does, and it works with comments in the `.env` file and new lines too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42255589/736809

Comment: What works for me was `env_vars: "{{ (env_file_content.content | b64decode).split('\n') | map('regex_replace', '^#.*', '') | select | map('regex_replace', '([^=]*)=(.*)', '\\1: \\2') | join('\n') | from_yaml }}"` - This removes commented lines from env file,

Now the set fact variable (`env_vars`) can be used to fetch the env keys like `env_vars["Key1"]` ..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Makefile to run ansible playbooks,

AND  you are running playbook only on localhost (not on a remote host)
you can use following:

cat Makefile:

```
include .env_file_name
export

run-myplaybook:
    ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml -i hosts.yml
```

Then run it:

```
make run-myplaybook
```